# Front end implementation if my resolver has nothing to display

Tags: jss

**Version and Environment**: Sitecore 9.1  + JSS(React)

**What I am doing**: 
I have the requirement to handle the un-authenticated users if they try to access a page which is for authenticated users only.

I extended the resolver to redirect the unauthenticated user to another page and that part is working fine.

When an authenticated user is coming to such a page, I am returning a null object as I have nothing to render on the UI.

**What is the problem**: In the browser, I am seeing a message that "JSS component is missing React implementation."

What should be the proper way of handling such a scenario?